Which Lucas numbers are perfect powers?
Are there any members of the bisection of the Lucas numbers $L_{2n}$ of the form $2^k, k > 1$? How about $d^k, k > 1$ for $d$ prime, and finally if $d$ is any composite integer? My hunch is that these are very sparse. Any pointers/resources are welcome.
I found Alfred, 1964 that talked about prime factors but not specifically about powers and Cohn, 1964 that talks about square Fibonacci numbers but these are both far from what I need.

Cf. this math overflow question

Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Did you mean $k\color{red}>1$?

yes, it was a typo. Also wow, what are the chances for having such a similar question on the same day. Haven't seen it. Thanks for the pointer.

According to Bugeaud et al., 2006, which is referenced in this MathOverflow question,
$L_3=2^2$
is the only perfect power in the Lucas sequence (besides $L_1=1$).
